# echelon form of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering why the augmented matrix $M_1$ is in echelon form, while the augmented matrix $M_2$ is not in echelon form.

$M_1 = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & -3 & 2 & -4 & : & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -3 & 2 & : & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & : & 0\\ \end{array} } \right] , \space M_2 = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & -3 & : & 2 \\ 0 & -7 & 7 & : & -3\\0 & 0 & 0 & : & 0\\ \end{array} } \right]$

What else (properties) should I look in the matrices so that I can tell the difference between echelon form and non echelon form?

Thanks..

Comment: they usually want each row to begin with $1$ unless it is all $0$

Comment: Actually, here I am wanting to ask about echelon form, not row reduced echelon form. The answer to the question in which these matrices are given says that the variables associated to 1st and 3rd columns in $M_1$ are not free whereas for 2nd, 4th and 5th in $M_1$, they are free. For $M_2$ they write - " The notion of free variables applies only to a system in echelon form ". We can easily divide the second row by -7 and say that the variable associated to the 3rd column in $M_2$ is free while the variables associated to 1st and 2nd in $M_2$ are not; but they don't write so. I was wondering why

Answer (score 0):

$M_2$ is not in row  echelon form because the leading number in each row must be **one**.

A matrix $A$ is in row  echelon form if:

(i) all zero rows are at the bottom, and

(ii) the leading coefficient in each row is a one and is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.

Comment: Leading entries are all one is the requirement for reduced echelon form not for echelon form.

Comment: Depends on the book I guess. My book said they had to be $1$.